# VSTO on online ver of MS Project

Tags: vsto, ms-project

I developed an add-in for MS Project. However, my company opted to use the Office 365 online version. Which means employees do not need to install MS Project on their local machine. How will be able to use the add-in I created? Or how will I create an add-in for the online ver of MS Project?

Thanks,
Gilbert